# Best way to pass delegate parameters

Tags: c#, delegates

What is the best way to pass parameters through to a delegate? I can see benefits for both of the following ways so I would like to know the most used and industry accepted way of doing it:

**1) Pass any parameters individually with each parameters being just that, a parameter.**

Example Delegate

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(bool PARAM1, String PARAM2, int PARAM3);
```

**2) Pass any parameters through a struct and the only parameter of the delegate is that struct.**

Example Struct

```
public struct MyDelegateArgs
{
    public bool PARAM1;
    public String PARAM2;
    public int PARAM3;
}
```

Example Delegate

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(MyDelegateArgs args);
```

Comment: what do you perceive being the benefit of the first approach?

Comment: I see the main benefit as there being less code but I can also see the benefit of having the code somewhere else (in a struct in a separate file).

Comment: The only benefit of using a struct of parameters is if you're going to have many parameters to pass or another delegates which have the same parameters.

Comment: If parameters more than four or five then use second approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine your struct had 20 properties / fields - would you really want to pass all of those in as parameters? Generally I would argue to hide all of this complexity and keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by passing in a class / struct instead - this in most cases is also more expressive - your delegates needs a parameter of type `MyDelegateArgs`.

The only argument I could come up with for passing in individual values is if you only need a small subset that just happen to be used in `MyDelegateArgs` but are otherwise unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

If your delegate has utility as an `Action<T>` or a `Predicate<T>`, using the struct argument is preferable as it will keep you from tripping over a case where the signature gets too large for the predefined `Action` or `Predicate` definitions when you go to extend the delegate's signature.